# Bidirectional Virtualization in the Windows store apps

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-store-apps, windows-8.1

I have a requirement like to load the data in the Bidirectional Virtualization in my ItemsControl.

VirtualizingStackPanel basically supports either Horizontal or Vertical orientation support. Is there any way to achieve this in Windows Store apps ?

Comment: Do you mean like a grid where you can scroll either horizontally or vertically and possibly almost infinitely in any direction? `ListView` supports virtualization by default. If you want to customize virtualization - you'll need to implement it yourself since the virtualization support in list controls is not extensible.

Comment: By default ListView supports Virtualization in only one direction. But I need Virtualization in both the direction. But if I try to inherit OrientedVirtualizingPanel and VirtualizingPanel, These panels does not support inheritance. Could you please suggest me if there is any other option ?

Comment: As I said - you would need to implement your own virtualized list control from scratch. To make it more interesting - I would recommend doing that with Direct2D. :) If you need something so different - you're just going to be better off doing it at the low level.

Answer (score 0):

One thing I might try if I really wanted to hack support for what you are saying into the existing controls would be to split your list into two and bind them to two `ListViews`, then put the `ListViews` in a `StackPanel`, the `StackPanel` into a `ScrollViewer` and apply some `RenderTransforms` to the upper `ListView` and its items to make it scroll up instead of down when you first load it. Oh and make sure to synchronize the sizes of the inner `ListViews` to the size of the outer `ScrollViewer` so that when you reach that transition point - the outer `ScrollViewer` would serve to flip between the visible `ListViews`.